# How to logout the current user from /wp-admin without notices and warnings?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to avoid the WordPress subscriber users to have access to admin. I'm using the following code:

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'lr_no_admin_u_access', 100 );
function lr_no_admin_u_access() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    $redirect = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : site_url();
    
    if($user_role !== 'editor' && $user_role !== 'administrator'){
        wp_logout();
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect);
        exit;
    }
}
```

When a user navigates to `/wp-admin`, should be logged out and redirected to the home page. Instead, a white page full of notices and warnings appears. Examples of errors:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/[site]/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1911

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/[site]/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php:1911) in /home/[site]/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6270

... And many more. and many more. Why? How to avoid?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple approach using the 'init' hook, which is a good one for this type of tasks.

This will prevent all users who are not administrators to navigate to `/wp-admin`:

```
  function xlopez_redirect_to_home_nonadmins() {
        if (is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator')) {
            wp_safe_redirect(home_url(), 302);
            exit;
        }
  }
  add_action('init', 'xlopez_redirect_to_home_nonadmins');
```